# Magento and ERP

Tags: magento-enterprise, orders

We're in the process of re-developing our e-commerce site (previously osCommerce) in Magento EE (1.2.1).  While Magento does a pretty good job on the ecommerce side of things there is a still a large gap we need to cover on things like:

- Forecasting inventory and issuing purchase orders to vendors
- Basic warehouse management tasks (receiving, picking, packing, inventory adjustments, inventory locations, etc.)

We've looked at different solutions like Netsuite which we weren't extremely happy with due to integration and the closed nature of their platform.  We do a lot of what we call mass customization on our orders - they require a fair amount of work before they can be shipped.  We also briefly committed to OpenERP until we discovered the commercial support here in the US is not great.

What is everyone using for an ERP?  Are you creating your own solutions?

Comment: This doesn't seem relevant to Magento.  While Magento may have a few features that relate to ERP (stock/inventory management, mostly...) it is not a replacement or substitute for an ERP system.  I would ignore the words ERP if your revenues are under $100M and focus on the specifics of what you need -- inventory management, work order management, etc.  You will probably end up spending a lot on development regardless of what tool/platform you choose.

Comment: @Ralph While I understand what you're saying, I've worked for a number of startups and sub-$100M companies that couldn't survive without ERP. ERP could be defined as Quickbooks Enterprise - it doesn't have to be elaborate or expensive; and nobody would suggest running a $50M business on spreadsheets and email alone...

Comment: At that point SAP Business One or Netsuite would not exist, however you should only consider an ERP when revenues are in the $millions. OpenBravo matches the Magento business model and you now have SAP ByDesign, OpenERP is too community based to match Magento so we avoided it. If you are going to use an ERP do it properly, stick to the well know ones.

Comment: Magento openerp connector is a brilliant solution for connecting with the openerp and magento https://store.webkul.com/Magento-Extensions/Magento-OpenERP-Bridge.html

Comment: try linnwork if that fits in your requirement. we are using it for stock management. PS, Of course, its third part paid service.

Answer (score 2):

We have a Magento Enterprise client on the same version of EE as you that's using the Embedded ERP extension - http://www.magento-erp.com/

It's not inexpensive (590 Euros, or about $800 at current exchange rates), and it doesn't claim support for Magento EE 1.12 (our EE client that's using it is on EE 1.12, though, and using it successfully).

It embeds basically all of the functionality that you're looking for into your Magento admin. Originally, I wasn't a big fan of that - I like to keep separate systems separate, and I've seen too many big ERP projects go wrong very quickly, so I wanted to keep the ERP out of Magento itself, but our client specifically wanted the ERP to be embedded into the Magento admin.

We have had to patch the extension quite a bit - we've actually written our own extension specifically for our client called 'ErpFixes' that fixes a number of annoyances with the extension, so I have a hard time giving it a solid recommendation, however, if you're interested in integrating all of these various features into your Magento Enterprise backend, it's your best choice that we've seen thus far.

Personally, if you have the budget for it, I'm all for implementing a custom system that does exactly what you need, no more, no less. We've implemented custom order/warehouse/inventory management systems for our clients that cost significantly less than what it cost to implement something like OpenERP. But if you want to go with something 'off the shelf', the closest match to your requirements that I'm aware of is the Embedded ERP extension.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few open-source and some paid solutions out there that are specific to synchronizing OpenERP and Magento. Here are a couple of options, neither of which I have any actual experience with:

**OpenERP Connector (Magento Connect)**

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/open-erp-connector-by-openlabs.html

- It looks very popular
- reviews aren't great for current 1.7 CE release (the version 1.12 is based on)
- Many people suggest downloading it directly from Launchpad at https://code.launchpad.net/~magentoerpconnect-core-editors/magentoerpconnect/module-magento-trunk

**Smile Synchro**

http://code.google.com/p/magento-openerp-smile-synchro/

- This is purely a Google Code repo for their open-source connector
- No other feedback about this other than to say it's at least an option to have on your radar
- No community feedback that i can see (other than a long defect list under *Issues*)

If you're open to other solutions, you can always code your own with 3rd party modules such as the ones from Xtento - I have had great luck with them. Most of these will allow you to manage your ERP-type functionality like Inventory, PO's, AR/AP, Shipping/Warehousing, etc. with at the base minimum one-way connection (*from* Magento *to* the ERP solution). I've personally implemented these extensions with A2000.

http://www.xtento.com/

Best of luck.